# Menor unidade de tempo possível

Tags: benchmark

Qual seria a menor unidade de tempo que atualmente é possível medir usando computadores comuns?

Até onde sei,baseado no relógio do computador são milissegundos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O mais rápido que consegue são nanosegundos e a [resolução máxima depende do processador](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343188/precise-linux-timing-what-determines-the-resolution-of-clock-gettime):

```c
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
   timespec ts;
   // clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts); // Para FreeBSD
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts); // Para Linux
}
```

Comment: O `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` é apenas para o FreeBSD ou para todos os BSD?

Comment: Amigo,se a resolução do processador for muito grande,é possível que haja uma dessincroniza entre os computadores mesmo que "um dia" ajustados ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: @Patrick testei apenas no FreeBSD, mas uma [pesquisa rápida](https://www.google.ca/search?q=CLOCK_MONOTONIC+openbsd) me indicou que também está presente no NetBSD e no OpenBSD mas não no Mac OS X.

Comment: @WeslleyCXSardinha depende muito de como ajustar esses computadores, mas não porque a resolução muda o qual o mínimo. E em unidades maiores (minutos/segundos) a sincronia permanescerá. Agora se quer sincronia em nanosegundos, neste caso sim não haverá sincronia permanente.

Comment: Tal assincronia pode ser prevista ou é obtida através de efeitos aleatórios?

Comment: Leia [esse artigo](http://www.ntp.br/NTP/MenuNTPTempo)